# publishing Sails / Node.js to Kongregate

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, csrf, kongregate

So, finally my MMORTS game built on Sails is going to Kongregate.
Had few obstacles, like connecting websockets, but solved now.
Probably the last obstacle is to keep authenticated session. I was using frameworks everywhere and i have no idea how does the authentication sessions work under the hood. 
The main problem is probably the CSRF or CORS.
 I am using Sails v1.0.
So, i start with HTML, which I upload to kongregate. I'm taking the simplest possible example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn1.kongregate.com/javascripts/kongregate_api.js'></script>

    <script src="sails.io.js"
      autoConnect="false"
      environment="production"
      headers='{ "x-csrf-token": "" }'
    ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      io.sails.url = 'https://my-secret-game.com'; // or where you want
    </script>

  </head>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

And this is the main.js , which I also upload to kongregate

```
kongregateAPI.loadAPI(function(){
  window.kongregate = kongregateAPI.getAPI();
  var username = kongregate.services.getUsername();
  var id = kongregate.services.getUserId();
  var token = kongregate.services.getGameAuthToken();

  $.get("https://my-secret-game.com/csrfToken", function (data, jwres) {

    var params = {
      username: username,
      id: id,
      token: token,
      _csrf: data._csrf
    };

    $.post("https://my-secret-game.com/kong", params, function(data, jwr, xhr){

      // cant set the cookie - because of chrome. this doesnt work
      document.cookie = document.cookie + ';authenticated=true;sails.sid=' + data.id;

      $.get("https://my-secret-game.com/csrfToken", function (data, jwres) {
        var msg = {
          testing_authentication: true,
          _csrf: data._csrf
        };
        $.post("https://my-secret-game.com/test", msg, function(data, status){
          // getting the 403 Forbidden, CSRF mismatch. trying to access 
          // the play/test route, which is protected by sessionAUTH
          console.log('data.response', data.response)
        });

      });
    });
  });
});
```

The problem is, that i am getting 403 Forbidden whenever I try to POST my Sails backend with sessionAUTH. I also cant set cookies - probably because of Chrome. What can I do? When i get CSRF token, on the next request my Sails app responds about CSRF mismatch. It becomes wrong.

And this is the controller on my Sails backend server

```
module.exports = {
  kong: function (req, res, next) {
    var url = 'https://api.kongregate.com/api/authenticate.json';
    var kong_api_key = 'my-secred-api-key';
    var params = req.allParams();
    var request = require('request');

    var req_form = {
      "api_key": kong_api_key,
      "user_id": params.id,
      "game_auth_token": params.token
    };

    request({
        url: url,
        method: "POST",
        json: true,
        body: req_form,
        timeout: 5000
    }, function (err, response, body){
       if(err) { console.log(err, 'ERR43'); return res.ok(); }
       else {
        if(!response.body.success) {
          console.log('unsuccessful login from kongregate')
          return res.ok();
        }

        // trying to use a existing user and authenticate to it
        User.find({username: 'admin-user'}).exec(function(err, users) {
          var user = users[0];
          req.session.authenticated = true;
          req.session.user = { id: user.id };

          // trying to send session_id, so that i could hold it on kongregates cookies as `sid`
          return res.send({ user: user, id: req.session.id });

        });
       }
    });
  },
```

Could somoene please help to fix authentication and CSRF of my app?

In case needs more info about my configs, this is the config/session.js

```
var prefixes = 'dev';

module.exports.session = {
  secret: 'my-secret',

  cookie: {
     secure: false
  },

  adapter: 'redis',

  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6379,
  ttl: 3000000,
  db: 0,
  prefix: prefixes + 'sess:',
};
```

config/policies.js

```
module.exports.policies = {
  user: {
    'new':    'flash',
    'create': 'flash',
    'edit':   'rightUser',
    'update': 'rightUser',
    '*':      'sessionAuth'
  },
  play: {
    '*': 'sessionAuth'
  }
};
```

api/policies/sessionAuth.js

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.authenticated) {
    return next();
  } else {
    var requireLoginErr = [
      { name: 'requireLogin', message: 'You must be signed in' }
    ];
    req.session.flash = {
      err: requireLoginErr
    };
    res.redirect('/');
    return;
  }
};
```

config/security.js

```
module.exports.security = {
    csrf: true,
  cors: {
    allowRequestMethods: 'GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS,HEAD',
    allowRequestHeaders: 'content-type,Access-Token',
    allowResponseHeaders: '*',
    allRoutes: true,
    allowOrigins: '*',
    allowCredentials: false,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, since i had no answers (obviously - the question was bad), answering with my solution which i have solved by my self - so the next time i can read my self. Not sure how good it is, but at least it works.

Sails CORS is taken form Express.js and allows to connect sockets to kongregate if i allow it inside configs.
But it does not allow to authenticate in a normal way, by sending sails.sid (authentication token) via cookies.

Chrome does not allow to set cookies with javascript (i dont have backend on Kongregate) to headers at all due to security. So, if i can't send cookies with headers, Sails can't authenticate the requests in a normal way. Even if i allow CORS to accept the 'cookie' header - it's not allowed by browsers to set cookie headers with javascript.

I can make some unique header like "authentication" and set the sails.sid there, extend some core functionality of Sails to take this new header instead of cookie header. But the problem - on Sails backed i was not able to get at all this sails.sid and send it to my external frontend.. Where it is created? How can i get sails.sid on Sails backend? Not sure - can't google it.

So, i just did authentication in a most simple way possible - on account login/register, i just create a session key by my self - with bcrypt hashing user_id+secret_token (taken from sails config secrets). and sending to the frontend { user_id: 'abcd', secret_token: 'a2dw412515...' }

I have made my policies in Sails to authenticate on every POST/GET request - take the request's session_id and user_id, and compare using bcrypt, does the session_id is the same as encrypted user_id+secret_token. I hope its secure enough.

So, it worked. I just had to disable CSRF. Maybe some day i will implement it again, I just have to write it in my way, not leave the Sails defaults.

The working code:

FRONTEND

```
// you upload this HTML file to kongregate
// also you upload additionally ZIP named "kongregate_uploaded_folder" with libraries like sails.io, jquery

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="kongregate_uploaded_folder/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src='https://cdn1.kongregate.com/javascripts/kongregate_api.js'></script>
    <script src="kongregate_uploaded_folder/sails.io.js"
      autoConnect="false"
      environment="production"
    ></script>
  </head>

  <body style="padding:0; margin:0; overflow:hidden;">

  <div style="position:absolute; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
    <canvas id="main_canvas" style="position:absolute;" width="640" height="480" >Best initial resolution to have in Kongregate</canvas>
  </div>

  <script>
    // the first thing happends - you try to connect your frontend with Kongregate
    kongregateAPI.loadAPI(function(){
      window.kongregate = kongregateAPI.getAPI();

      if(!kongregate.services.isGuest()) {
        var params = {
          username: kongregate.services.getUsername(),
          id: kongregate.services.getUserId(),
          token: kongregate.services.getGameAuthToken(),
        };

        // call your backend to create a new session and give you session_id
        $.post("https://your_game_server.com/kong", params, function(data, jwr, xhr){
          var kong_session_id = data.kong_session_id;
          var kong_user_id = data.kong_user_id;
          var user = data.user;

          // connect your sockets with the server in this way
          io.socket = io.sails.connect("https://your_game_server.com", { useCORSRouteToGetCookie: false, reconnection: true });

          // subscribe to the global sockets channel. You have to make this route and code, but here is a example
          io.socket.get('/subscribe', { kong_session_id: kong_session_id, kong_user_id: kong_user_id }, function(data, jwr){
            if (jwr.statusCode == 200){
              io.socket.on(data.room, function(event){
                // on any server-side event, you will get this "event" message. At this part you decide what to do with this data
                incoming_socket_event(event); // i wont write this function
              });
              // your game continues here:
              $.get("https://your_game_server.com/player_data?kong_session_id=" + kong_session_id + "&kong_user_id=" + kong_user_id, params, function(data, jwr, xhr){
              // you will get authenticated "current_user"
            }
          });

        })
      }
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

BACKEND

```
// SAILS BACKEND:   home_controller.js
module.exports = {
  kong: function (req, res, next) {
    // player has already opened your game in kongregate.com and frontend requests this endpoint POST /kong { id: 84165456, token: 'as54..' }
    // you need to create a new session for this player, or register this player. This is your own session creation, since default sails session wont work with external website frontend.
    var req_params = {
      url: "https://api.kongregate.com/api/authenticate.json", // default URL to validate kongregate user
      method: "POST",
      json: true,
      body: { 
        api_key: 'gg000g00-c000-4c00-0000-c00000f2de8', // kongregate will provide this api-key for server-side connection (this one has some letters replaced)
        user_id: 84165456, // when frontend requests POST /kong { id=84165456 } , this 84165456 is provided by kongregate in the frontend
        game_auth_token: "as54a45asd45fs4aa54sf" // when frontend requests POST /kong { token = 'as54..' }, this is provided by kongregate in the frontend
      },
      timeout: 20000
    }

    // request kongregate that this is the real player and you will get a username
    request(req_params, function (err, response, body){
      var response_params = response.body; // response from kongregate API

      // search for user with this kongregate_id inside your database, maybe he is already registered, and you need just to create a new session.
      User.find({ kongregate_id: response_params.user_id }).exec(function(err, usr) {
        var user = usr[0]

        // if player already has an account inside your online game
        if(user) {
          // create new session for this user.
          require('bcryptjs').hash("your_own_random_secret_key" + user.id, 10, function sessionCreated(err, kong_session_id) {

            // send this info to frontend, that this player has been connected to kongregate
            return res.send({ 
              user: user, 
              kong_session_id: kong_session_id, 
              kong_user_id: user.id 
            });
          });            

        //if this is new user, you need to register him
        } else { 
          var allowedParams = {
            username: response_params.username, // kongregate will give you this player username
            email: 'you_have_no_email@kong.com', // kongregate does not provide email
            password: 'no_password_from_kongregate',
            kongregate_id: response_params.user_id // kongregate will give you this player id
          };

          User.create(allowedParams, function(err, new_user) {
            // create new session for this user.
            require('bcryptjs').hash("your_own_random_secret_key" + new_user.id, 10, function sessionCreated(err, kong_session_id) {

              // send this info to frontend, that this player has been connected to kongregate
              return res.send({ 
                user: new_user, 
                kong_session_id: kong_session_id, 
                kong_user_id: new_user.id 
              });
            }); 
          });
        }
      });
    });
  },
};
```

ROUTES

```
    // config/routes.js
    module.exports.routes = {
      'GET /player_data': 'PlayController.player_data',
      'GET /subscribe': 'PlayController.subscribe',
      'POST /kong': {
         action: 'home/kong',
         csrf: false // kongregate is a external website and you will get CORS error without this
      },
    };
```

SECURITY

```
// config/security.js
module.exports.security = {
    csrf: false,
  cors: {
    allowOrigins: ['https://game292123.konggames.com'], // your game ID will be another, but in this style
    allowRequestMethods: 'GET,POST',
    allowRequestHeaders: 'Content-Type',
    allowResponseHeaders: '',
    allRoutes: true,
    allowCredentials: false,
  },
};
```

SOCKETS

```
// config/sockets.js
module.exports.sockets = {
  grant3rdPartyCookie: true,
  transports: ["websocket"],
  beforeConnect: function(handshake, cb) { return cb(null, true); },
};
```

CONFIG POLICIES

```
// /config/policies.js
module.exports.policies = {
  play: {'*': 'sessionAuth'},
};
```

API POLICIES

```
// /app/sessionAuth.js
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  var params = req.allParams();
  // your own session handling way to get the user from session token
  require('bcryptjs').compare("your_own_random_secret_key" + params.kong_user_id, params.kong_session_id, function(err, valid) {
    req.session.authenticated = true;
    req.session.user_id = params.kong_user_id;
    return next();
  });
};
```

CONTROLLER

```
// /api/controllers/PlayController.js
module.exports = {
    player_data: async function (req, res, next) {
        var users = await User.find(req.session.user_id);
        return res.send({ current_user: users[0] });
    },
    subscribe: async function (req, res, next) {
      var users = await User.find(req.session.user_id);
      var roomName = String(users[0].id);
      sails.sockets.join(req.socket, roomName);
      res.json({ room: roomName });
    },
}
```